# On Centos 7 Cannot log in to the MySQL server (phpMyAdmin)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, centos7, mysql-8.0

I use the **repository mysql80-community-release-el7-3.noarch.rpm** to install Mysql 8.0.16 on Centos 7 with Apache 2.4.6, PHP 5.4.16 and phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.10. When I try to login with **root** at domain.com/phpmyadmin I getting `Cannot log in to the MySQL server` but with CLI I can.

Configuration of `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf`

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require all granted
       #Require ip 127.0.0.1
       #Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Mysql status:

```
mysql> STATUS;
--------------
mysql  Ver 8.0.18 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Connection id:          20
Current database:
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Current pager:          stdout
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         8.0.18 MySQL Community Server - GPL
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    utf8mb4
Db     characterset:    utf8mb4
Client characterset:    utf8mb4
Conn.  characterset:    utf8mb4
UNIX socket:            /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Uptime:                 1 hour 33 min 39 sec

Threads: 2  Questions: 80  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 201  Flush tables: 3  Open tables: 121  Queries per second avg: 0.014
```

Netstat `netstat -atnlp|grep -i "3306\|mysql"` retunrs:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::33060                :::*                    LISTEN      27697/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      27697/mysqld
```

Configuration of `/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * phpMyAdmin configuration file, you can use it as base for the manual
 * configuration. For easier setup you can use "setup/".
 *
 * All directives are explained in Documentation.html and on phpMyAdmin
 * wiki <http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net>.
 */

/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'generated_blowfish_secret_key'; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */

/**
 * Server(s) configuration
 */
$i = 0;

// The $cfg['Servers'] array starts with $cfg['Servers'][1].  Do not use
// $cfg['Servers'][0]. You can disable a server config entry by setting host
// to ''. If you want more than one server, just copy following section
// (including $i incrementation) serveral times. There is no need to define
// full server array, just define values you need to change.
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = 'localhost'; // MySQL hostname or IP address
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '';          // MySQL port - leave blank for default port
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']        = '';          // Path to the socket - leave blank for default socket
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';       // How to connect to MySQL server ('tcp' or 'socket')
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysqli';    // The php MySQL extension to use ('mysql' or 'mysqli')
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']      = FALSE;       // Use compressed protocol for the MySQL connection
                                                    // (requires PHP >= 4.3.0)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']   = '';          // MySQL control user settings
                                                    // (this user must have read-only
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']   = '';          // access to the "mysql/user"
                                                    // and "mysql/db" tables).
                                                    // The controluser is also
                                                    // used for all relational
                                                    // features (pmadb)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'cookie';    // Authentication method (config, http or cookie based)?
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = '';          // MySQL user
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = '';          // MySQL password (only needed
                                                    // with 'config' auth_type)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['only_db']       = '';          // If set to a db-name, only
                                                    // this db is displayed in left frame
                                                    // It may also be an array of db-names, where sorting order is relevant.
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db']       = '';          // Database name to be hidden from listings
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose']       = '';          // Verbose name for this host - leave blank to show the hostname

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb']         = '';          // Database used for Relation, Bookmark and PDF Features
                                                    // (see scripts/create_tables.sql)
                                                    //   - leave blank for no support
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'phpmyadmin'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = '';          // Bookmark table
                                                    //   - leave blank for no bookmark support
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_bookmark'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation']      = '';          // table to describe the relation between links (see doc)
                                                    //   - leave blank for no relation-links support
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_relation'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info']    = '';          // table to describe the display fields
                                                    //   - leave blank for no display fields support
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_table_info'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords']  = '';          // table to describe the tables position for the PDF schema
                                                    //   - leave blank for no PDF schema support
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_table_coords'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages']     = '';          // table to describe pages of relationpdf
                                                    //   - leave blank if you don't want to use this
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_pdf_pages'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info']   = '';          // table to store column information
                                                    //   - leave blank for no column comments/mime types
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_column_info'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history']       = '';          // table to store SQL history
                                                    //   - leave blank for no SQL query history
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_history'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose_check'] = TRUE;        // set to FALSE if you know that your pma_* tables
                                                    // are up to date. This prevents compatibility
                                                    // checks and thereby increases performance.
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowRoot']     = TRUE;        // whether to allow root login
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowDeny']['order']           // Host authentication order, leave blank to not use
                                     = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowDeny']['rules']           // Host authentication rules, leave blank for defaults
                                     = array();
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword']              // Allow logins without a password. Do not change the FALSE
                                     = FALSE;       // default unless you're running a passwordless MySQL server
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords']              // Leave blank (default) for no Designer support, otherwise
                                     = '';          // set to suggested 'pma_designer_coords' if really needed
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_garbage_threshold']         // Blobstreaming: Recommented default value from upstream
                                     = 50;          //   DEFAULT: '50'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_repository_threshold']      // Blobstreaming: Recommented default value from upstream
                                     = '32M';       //   DEFAULT: '32M'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_temp_blob_timeout']         // Blobstreaming: Recommented default value from upstream
                                     = 600;         //   DEFAULT: '600'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_temp_log_threshold']        // Blobstreaming: Recommented default value from upstream
                                     = '32M';       //   DEFAULT: '32M'
/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

/*
 * Directories for saving/loading files from server
 */
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '/var/lib/phpMyAdmin/upload';
$cfg['SaveDir']   = '/var/lib/phpMyAdmin/save';

/*
 * Disable the default warning that is displayed on the DB Details Structure
 * page if any of the required Tables for the relation features is not found
 */
$cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning'] = TRUE;

/*
 * phpMyAdmin 4.4.x is no longer maintained by upstream, but security fixes
 * are still backported by downstream.
 */
$cfg['VersionCheck'] = FALSE;
?>
```

Please help and thanks!

### **UPDATE**

Adding this to /etc/my.cfg

```
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
character-set-server = utf8mb4
```

And execute this `ALTER USER root@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'mypassword';` on mysql.

I can login.

Comment: You can try https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/ for mysql. it's better.

Comment: Thanks, but I've been reading and the workbench has no web application? (Im wrong ?)

And my server is in a VLAN which means I don't have direct access.

Comment: Could you please try changing the line `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';` from 'tcp' to 'socket? I believe what you're seeing here is two different users, one of which has permissions to connect. Using the other connection method would allow you to connect as the 'localhost' user in this case.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch nothing, still not working.